# Android 6.0 secure intents involving permissions

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

I have a question about the SDK 23 permission system. I guess it's easier with an example.

I have an app to share images. From the app you can tap an image and share to popular messaging apps. The current system is saving a Bitmap to the `getExternalCacheDir()` and share the Uri in the intent. Let's say I want to share to Hangouts.

- Scenario 1: The user has already authorized Hangouts to access Media. It works.
- Scenario 2: The user has not authorized yet Hangouts to access Media. When sharing, an error is logged because Hangouts does not have the permissions to read from Media.

My problem is that when sending the intent I cannot know if the user has already authorized Hangouts to read from Storage.

Is there a way to check if other apps "respond" to tasks involving permissions? Is there a way I don't know of to do this in a safe way without crashy experiences for the user?

Thanks!

Comment: The better answer is: don't pass a file path. Pass a `content://` `Uri` pointing to a `FileProvider` that serves the file. Then, the recipient does not need the permission at all. I [blogged about this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/10/07/runtime-permissions-files-action-send.html) ~3 weeks ago.

Comment: I asked the same question in the G+ community and got the same answer. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C28pvd2plBA) I was able to make it work with Hangouts and Gmail. Sadly, as you mention in your post, many apps assume Uri IS a file. I am going to try with a modified provider as suggested. Thanks @CommonsWare!